# How to filter array of object inside the array of the object type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm facing one issue with one of the API responses,
I have a response something like the below one.

```
[
  {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "US"}, {type: "County", countyName: "US"}, {type: "County", countyName: "US"}]},
  {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "German"}, {type: "County", countyName: "German"}, {type: "County", countyName: "German"}]},
  {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "Japan"}, {type: "County", countyName: "German"}, {type: "County", countyName: "German"}]},
]
```

it looks like an array of objects inside that have countries also the arrays of the object type. I need all the countyName in a single array for all the array of elements. like the below one type,

```
newNames = [US, German, Japan];
```

I tried something like this. but I couldn't able to get the output. can you please help me to do this?  thank you all.

```
let newNames = this.selectedStateList.filter(item => item.countries.forEach(item => item.countries)).map(ele => ele.countries.forEach(item => item.countries))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look through each `countries` object and add your data in a `Set` to get unique country.

```js
const data = [ {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "US"}, {type: "County", countyName: "US"}, {type: "County", countyName: "US"}]}, {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "German"}, {type: "County", countyName: "German"}, {type: "County", countyName: "German"}]}, {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "Japan"}, {type: "County", countyName: "German"}, {type: "County", countyName: "German"}]}, ],
      result = Array.from(data.reduce((r, {countries}) => {
        countries.forEach(({countyName}) => r.add(countyName));
        return r;
      }, new Set()));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `.map`s, not `.forEach` -  .map`transforms each element of an array, but`forEach` does not return anything.

After getting an array of arrays of country names, you can flatten with `.flat()` - or you can put them together and use `flatMap` instead.

```js
const input = [
  {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "US"}]},
  {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "German"}]},
  {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "Japan"}]},
];

const output = input.flatMap(
  obj => obj.countries.map(
    country => country.countyName
  )
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: It's working great, I modified something in my question, can you please help in that format. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```js
const arr = [
  {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "US"}]},
  {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "German"}]},
  {type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{type: "County", countyName: "Japan"}]}
]


const result = arr.reduce((acc,val)=>{
acc.push(val.countries[0].countyName)
return acc
},[] )

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Its working fine, but I modified something in my question, can you please help in that format. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the given response (array of objects), then reference the `countries` element and get it's first entry as it is also an array of objects:

```js
var input = [
    { type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{ type: "County", countyName: "US" }] },
    { type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{ type: "County", countyName: "German" }] },
    { type: "StateCountry", state: "AL", countries: [{ type: "County", countyName: "Japan" }] },
]
let output = []

for (const obj of input) {
    output.push(obj.countries[0].countyName)
}
console.log(output)
```

Comment: It's working great, I modified something in my question, can you please help in that format. thank you.